# Why <NavigationPage.TitleView> does not work in TabbedPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
 <NavigationPage >
        <x:Arguments>
            <controls:TabIconsPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
        <NavigationPage.TitleView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ImageButton Source="Taxi.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <controls:TabIconsPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
        <NavigationPage.TitleView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ImageButton Source="Taxi.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    </NavigationPage>
```

I want to make a tabbed page with different images in tabbar but it does not work.Please help.I want to make different size of images

[image]

what I want

[image]

what I have

[image]
[image]

I want like on the first screen and change size of icons

Comment: can you share want you want and what you are getting

Comment: I edit.I want tabbed page with 4 pages which have in tabbar different images with different size.When I use my code I have tabbed page without images in tabbar

Comment: https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-icons-in-navigation-toolbar/

Comment: How can I change the size of icon?

Comment: I dont think you can change the size of icon in navigation bar. May be you can create custom nav bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why <NavigationPage.TitleView> does not work in TabbedPage?

[TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar) should be set in each specific `ContentPage` instead of in `TabbedPage`. So in your page, you should config the TitleView in `controls:TabIconsPage`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="controls:TabIconsPage">
    
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ImageButton Source="Taxi.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            <ImageButton Source="Taxi.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            <ImageButton Source="Taxi.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
        ...
</ContentPage>
```

> How can I change the size of icon?

Try to use a icon with small size or set the WidthRequest/HeightRequest with a smaller value.

Comment: I added my question with your advice, please look

Comment: I did as you said

Comment: If you want to three images in the navigationbar, you should put three image there. See my updated code.

Comment: @MariaKamenskyh 
Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).